# Ubuntu 20.04 network via USB docking station unstable on Dell Precision 5510

Tags: networking, usb, 20.04

I am using a Notebook Dell Precision 5510 connected to an i-tec USB3 Docking Station, which has a network plugged in. All other devices connected to the docking station like monitor, keyboard, mouse, USB-sticks do work fine.

When I am using network wired via USB the connection is pretty unstable. Works - does not work - works...

When I switch to wifi everything is fine.

My previous (noname) notebook with 18.04 worked like a charm using the same docking station.

Any ideas?

Do I need specific network drivers or other stuff?

Edit:

```
lsusb -t
/:  Bus 02.Port 1: Dev 1, Class=root_hub, Driver=xhci_hcd/10p, 5000M
    |__ Port 2: Dev 2, If 0, Class=Hub, Driver=hub/4p, 5000M
        |__ Port 1: Dev 3, If 0, Class=Vendor Specific Class, Driver=, 5000M
        |__ Port 1: Dev 3, If 1, Class=Application Specific Interface, Driver=, 5000M
        |__ Port 1: Dev 3, If 2, Class=Audio, Driver=snd-usb-audio, 5000M
        |__ Port 1: Dev 3, If 3, Class=Audio, Driver=snd-usb-audio, 5000M
        |__ Port 1: Dev 3, If 4, Class=Audio, Driver=snd-usb-audio, 5000M
        |__ Port 1: Dev 3, If 5, Class=Communications, Driver=cdc_ncm, 5000M
        |__ Port 1: Dev 3, If 6, Class=CDC Data, Driver=cdc_ncm, 5000M
        |__ Port 2: Dev 4, If 0, Class=Mass Storage, Driver=usb-storage, 5000M
/:  Bus 01.Port 1: Dev 1, Class=root_hub, Driver=xhci_hcd/16p, 480M
    |__ Port 2: Dev 2, If 0, Class=Hub, Driver=hub/4p, 480M
        |__ Port 4: Dev 4, If 0, Class=Hub, Driver=hub/4p, 480M
            |__ Port 3: Dev 6, If 1, Class=Human Interface Device, Driver=usbhid, 1.5M
            |__ Port 3: Dev 6, If 0, Class=Human Interface Device, Driver=usbhid, 1.5M
            |__ Port 4: Dev 7, If 2, Class=Audio, Driver=snd-usb-audio, 12M
            |__ Port 4: Dev 7, If 0, Class=Audio, Driver=snd-usb-audio, 12M
            |__ Port 4: Dev 7, If 3, Class=Human Interface Device, Driver=usbhid, 12M
            |__ Port 4: Dev 7, If 1, Class=Audio, Driver=snd-usb-audio, 12M
    |__ Port 4: Dev 3, If 1, Class=Wireless, Driver=btusb, 12M
    |__ Port 4: Dev 3, If 0, Class=Wireless, Driver=btusb, 12M
    |__ Port 12: Dev 5, If 0, Class=Video, Driver=uvcvideo, 480M
    |__ Port 12: Dev 5, If 1, Class=Video, Driver=uvcvideo, 480M
```

```
uname -r
5.4.0-7634-generic
```